# Overall project code coverage summary

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I have root module with sub-modules. I need one code coverage summary for the whole project (include all sub-modules).

Currently, with the attached *build.gradle* configuration, there is in the main directory a summary file (*jacoco/jacocoHtml/index.html*) with only the summary of the last sub-module (the last checked sub-module [I assume this is random]) and a separate directory for each package of each sub-module.

currently configuration:

```
jacocoTestReport {
        reports {
            xml.enabled false
            csv.enabled flase
            html.destination file("c:/jacoco/jacocoHtml")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Each subproject can run its own tests and produce its own separate coverage execution file, but don't have a `JacocoReport` task for each subproject.

Instead, use a [JacocoMerge](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoMerge.html) task to merge the individual execution files into one and then generate a single [JacocoReport](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoReport.html) from the merged execution file. You'll need to configure all class and source directories from the subprojects on the JacocoReport task

There's a [sample test here](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/28fa962a330ea6085ea324381eec4f31dcf92d1c/subprojects/jacoco/src/integTest/groovy/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/plugins/JacocoPluginMultiVersionIntegrationTest.groovy#L178) which merges two test tasks within a single project. This could be adapted for multi module